# Cannot print italics text from pod2usage()

Tags: perl

I am trying to output Pod text to the terminal using [`pod2usage()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Usage). It works fine for most cases, except for text formatted as italics using the Pod formatting syntax `I<text>`. In this case I expect the text to be printed underlined (this is how it works when using [Pod::Text::Termcap](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Text::Termcap) directly). For example (`prog.pl`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
BEGIN { $Pod::Usage::Formatter = 'Pod::Text::Termcap'; }
use Pod::Usage qw(pod2usage);

case1_use_termcap_directly();
case2_use_termcap_indirectly();

sub case2_use_termcap_indirectly {
    GetOptions(help => \my $help, test => \my $test);
    if ( $help ) {
        pod2usage(
            -message => "",
            -verbose => 2,
            -output  => \*STDERR
        );
    }
}

sub case1_use_termcap_directly {
    my $parser = Pod::Text::Termcap->new();
    $parser->output_string( \my $out_str );
    my $pod_str = do { local $/; <DATA> };
    $parser->parse_string_document( $pod_str );
    print $out_str;
}    
__DATA__

=head1 SYNOPSIS

prog [OPTIONS]

=head1 OPTIONS

=over 4

=item --help

Print this summary.

=item B<--test>=I<value>

Testing C<Pod::Text::Termcap>

=back

=head1 DESCRIPTION

A test program
```

The output of running `prog.pl --help` is:

[image]

Notice that the text `"value"` is underlined when using `Pod::Text::Termcap` directly, but not underlined when printed indirectly from `pod2usage()`.

Note: I am using Ubuntu 15.10. This worked fine for Ubuntu 14.10, so I expect the problem was introduced when I upgraded Perl modules.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally (i.e. pre-1990s) terminals couldn't do italics. Most of the nroff/man/etc... tooling flow just isn't set up to handle it. Additionally, your own terminal may not cope itself.

You can test your terminal itself by trying

```
$ echo -e "\e[3mitalics?\e[m"
```

and seeing if the result comes out in italics. If not, then your terminal definitely can't do it anyway.

Comment: Yes agree, I also thought that was the reason `Pod::Text::Termcap` underlined the text instead? Btw. I am using gnome-terminal, and it can do italics. But I think I am not interested in that feature ( I just want the text underlined)